# jQuery Validate with input arrays

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

The following code results in the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token ).

Any ideas?

```
$("#signupForm").validate({
    rules: {
        'entry[first_name]': "required",
        'answers[985575][answer]': "required",
        'answers[985574][answer]': {
        required: true,
        phoneUS: true
        },
        'entry[email]': {
        required: true,
        email: true
    }
    }});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `phoneUS` is not a standard, built-in rule. So unless you have defined it, it won't work. As explained in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/CustomMethods/phoneUS) you need to define it. They provide the following method that you need to include in order to define the `phoneUS` rule:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("phoneUS", function(phone_number, element) {
    phone_number = phone_number.replace(/\s+/g, ""); 
    return this.optional(element) || phone_number.length > 9 &&
        phone_number.match(/^(1-?)?(\([2-9]\d{2}\)|[2-9]\d{2})-?[2-9]\d{2}-?\d{4}$/);
}, "Please specify a valid phone number");
```

And here's a working [live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7VGya/3/).

Comment: Thanks! I had this in my code however I moved only part of the code and it was missing this.